# Prevent Javascript cacheing with django form assets

Tags: javascript, django, django-forms

I am using Django's form assets to create a new form widget which depends on a javascript file called newwidget.js, like this:-

```
class NewWidget(forms.TextInput):
    class Media:
        js = ('js/newwidget.js',)
```

If I update the javascript, how do I stop the user's browser from cacheing the file and not finding my changes?

I've used django compressor for other static files that I've used in templates but I can't see how to do it for this one.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried using django compressor?